# how to input value to database from 2 related option based on API data

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to input options value to database from 2 related option, the problem is the value on option is id, not the string. I successfully input value on 1 option value only, but i need 2 of that option value to inputted on my database.

here's my js code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadProvinsi('#oriprovince');
    loadProvinsi('#desprovince');
    $('#oriprovince').change(function(){
        $('#oricity').show();
        var idprovince = $('#oriprovince').val();
        loadCity(idprovince,'#oricity')
    });
});

function loadProvinsi(id){
    $('#oricity').hide();
    $('#descity').hide();
    $(id).html('loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=showprovince',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            $(id).html('');
            province = '';
                $.each(response['rajaongkir']['results'], function(i,n){
                    province = '<option value="'+n['province_id']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>';
                    province = province + '';
                    $(id).append(province);
                });
        },
        error:function(){
            $(id).html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
function loadCity(province,id){
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=showcity',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{province:province},
        success:function(response){
            $(id).html('');
            city = '';
                $.each(response['rajaongkir']['results'], function(i,n){
                    city = '<option value="'+n['city_id']+'">'+n['city_name']+'</option>';
                    city = city + '';
                    $(id).append(city);
                });
        },
        error:function(){
            $(id).html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
```

if i change to this line code :

```
province = '<option value="'+n['province']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>';
```

it successfully become string but the other option cant show the list of city because its based on province id, any suggestion like 2 value on option maybe ?

slice of register form registuser.php

```
                          <tr>
                            <td><label for="prov_usr">Provinsi</label></td>
                            <td>
                            <select name="prov_usr" id="oriprovince">
                            <option>Provinsi</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><label for="kota_usr">Kota</label></td>
                            <td>
                            <select name="kota_usr" id="oricity">
                            <option>Kota</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
```

slice of process.php

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once('idmore.php');
$IdmoreRO = new IdmoreRO();
if(isset($_GET['act'])):
    switch ($_GET['act']) {

        case 'showprovince':
            $province = $IdmoreRO->showProvince();
            echo $province;
        break;

        case 'showcity':
            $idprovince = $_GET['province'];
            $city = $IdmoreRO->showCity($idprovince);
            echo $city;
        break;
```

idmore.php (php class)

```
class IdmoreRO{
    private $key;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //masukan api key disini
        $this->key = '3f01f13ce2b42ba983ad3f3bc4852f84';    
    }
    //menampilkan data provinsi
    public function showProvince()
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://rajaongkir.com/api/starter/province",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "key: $this->key"
                ),
            ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
            $result = 'error';
            return 'error';
        } else {
            return $response;
        }
    }
    //menampilkan data kabupaten/kota berdasarkan id provinsi
    public function showCity($province)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://rajaongkir.com/api/starter/city?province=$province",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "key: $this->key"
                ),
            ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
            $result = 'error';
            return 'error';
        } else {
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Beginnings of sentences and the word "I" should always be capitalized. Please edit your question

Comment: This code look sooo familiar to me! But what is your question? I did nit understand it. If you want to input option values to database, what part of your code is exactly doing it?!

Comment: @EhsanT same project new problem, I tried to input value on option list, but the value is the ID not the city or Province name, I update the asked question

Comment: Where in your code you are trying to input value of option to db?! I can not see that code. or maybe you mean something else that I still have not understand.

Comment: If you want to get the text of the selected option, the posted answer by @phobia82 is correct, but it's really very extra work. you simple can get the text of selected option like this: `$('#oriprovince option:selected').text();` or if you are in the element event function, it's better to use this: `$(this).find("option:selected").text();`

Comment: @EhsanT oh i get it what you mean, its like get the exact value of selected option then make it to variable, after that use that variable to db.

im i right ? because i need it too in other page, i will try it now

Comment: @EhsanT he needs the text to submit to db, the string should be on the value attribute, but he also needs the id internally in the js code to query for the cities. Anyway I dont see the very extra work by just changing 2 lines of code.

Comment: If you need to send both of the `province_id` and `province(name)` to your _php_ then you have to get both of them like this: `var idprovince = $(this).val();` and `var provinceName = $(this).find("option:selected").text();` and then send both of them to your php

Comment: @phobia82, Since he is using ajax, there is no need to place the text in the value, because he has to handle the getting the text anyway and also when he has the text in the `.text()` adding another attribute to the element is extra work in my opinion. If only the form was being submitted, then your code was the better solution.

Comment: @ehsanT, phobia88 you 2 are have right answer and my function code not only works on 1 page, because i need it too on other page and different cases, but your code too give me solution on other case thats why i upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with the two values, the string to send to the server on submit, and the id to query for the cities in your ajax request. You will need to use the string in the value attribute since that's what the form will submit to the server, and add an additional attribute with the id so you can use it in the ajax request.

So to build the province select you can do this:

```
'<option value="'+n['province']+'" data-province_id="'+n['province_id']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>';
```

and where you get the province_id to query for the cities, access it like

```
var idprovince = $("#oriprovince option:selected").data("province_id");
```

Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadProvinsi('#oriprovince');
    loadProvinsi('#desprovince');
    $('#oriprovince').change(function(){
        $('#oricity').show();
        var idprovince = $("#oriprovince option:selected").data("province_id")
        loadCity(idprovince,'#oricity')
    });
});

function loadProvinsi(id){
    $('#oricity').hide();
    $('#descity').hide();
    $(id).html('loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=showprovince',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            $(id).html('');
            province = '';
                $.each(response['rajaongkir']['results'], function(i,n){
                    province = '<option value="'+n['province']+'" data-province_id="'+n['province_id']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>'
                    province = province + '';
                    $(id).append(province);
                });
        },
        error:function(){
            $(id).html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
function loadCity(province,id){
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=showcity',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{province:province},
        success:function(response){
            $(id).html('');
            city = '';
                $.each(response['rajaongkir']['results'], function(i,n){
                    city = '<option value="'+n['city_id']+'">'+n['city_name']+'</option>';
                    city = city + '';
                    $(id).append(city);
                });
        },
        error:function(){
            $(id).html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
```

You can use [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) or [jQuery.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: its work :) thats why i ask user here if option can use 2 values, but i didnt how it work, thx so much